# Lost LXDE menus after replacing /home

Tags: lubuntu, menu

I am trying Lubuntu on an old laptop.  I have before and after the install I had two partitions (+swap) mounting on `/` and on `/home`.  When I did the Lubuntu install I told it to ignore the `/home` partition.  After the Lubuntu install I logged in and everything appeared OK.

I mounted the /home partition as `/hold.old`.  Then I copied all the files from `/home` to `/home.old`.  Then for each user I chown'ed the stuff in `/home.old`.  Then I edited `/etc/fstab` to mount the /home partition.  Then I renamed `/home`.  Then I rebooted.

All my old files are where I expected them in the `/home` filesystem.  But my LXDE menu system is messed up.  Instead of the full menu system I only have terminal and logout.  I thought that most of the menu system lived in `/usr/share`.  But, apparently LXDE has some menu stuff in `/home` that I did not get copied over correctly.

Is there a quick way to restore the default LXDE menu system?
Can you point some documentation that would be good for learning the sysadmin level workings of LXDE?

Comment: Did you copy all the hidden directories (beginning with `"."`). `cp -a` should do that.

Comment: Yup, forgot the -a on the cp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just show all the hidden files using CTRL+H and then copy EVERYTHING. The configuration will be in /home somewhere. In a hidden file there could be alot of configurations. Especially in .config .